# ordering a vector in R while ignoring yet keeping NAs

Tags: r, vector, count, rank

If I have a vector `a = c(1300,NA,NA,NA,NA,1500,NA,NA,6000,NA,NA,900)`

How can I [order](/questions/tagged/order) this [vector](/questions/tagged/vector) to result in:

`b=[2,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,NA,NA,4,NA,NA,5]`?

Sidenote :I tried to make them repeat so it was

```
a=[1300,1300,1300,1300,1300,1500,1500,1500,6000,6000,6000,900]
```

But when I use rank its gets some crazy half numbers, any ideas? I'm at wits end for figuring this out.

Keeping the amount of NAs after a number is very important here so I cant just only ignore them

Comment: If we're ordering, shouldn't the final value be 1 instead of 5?

Answer (score 1):

```
replace(a, !is.na(a), rank(a[!is.na(a)], ties.method = "first"))
# [1]  2 NA NA NA NA  3 NA NA  4 NA NA  1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dplyr::dense_rank` function behaves as you want:

```
library(dplyr)
dense_rank(a)
# [1]  2 NA NA NA NA  3 NA NA  4 NA NA  1
```

It also works on the dense vector:

```
b = c(1300,1300,1300,1300,1300,1500,1500,1500,6000,6000,6000,900)
dense_rank(b)
# [1] 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Take `a ^ is.na(a)` and multiply it by `rank(a)`.  We use `ties="first"` to ensure we get increasing values at each index, not averages.

```
rank(a, ties="first") * a ^ is.na(a)
# [1]  2 NA NA NA NA  3 NA NA  4 NA NA  1
```

Comment: Assuming there's a typo in the question.  Since we're ordering, the last value should be 1.